# How can i record live audio using Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I have very simple question that is how can i live Audio using flex and save the recorded audio to the client system??
is there any way, we can do without any media server or red5??
as i have to learn server api also..
Any good links will be helpful..
Please guide me.. i need little guidance.. please help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [following link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html). It shows you how to capture data from the microphone.

Comment: Thanks for the link ... but it just allow u to save data in byteArray , i want to save as mp3 file on the client system.. For that, i think i have to use air application.. Am i right??

Comment: Not necessarily, FP10 allows some limited file interaction from the application. Not sure if you'd be able to make it do exactly what you want. AIR would certainly be the safest bet.